# error in retrieving mapping for action in struts1.2

Tags: java, struts

im stuck with this error n unable to find whr i went wrong

here is code..plz go through it 
im using myelipse,struts1.2

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts      Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>
<data-sources />
<form-beans />
<global-exceptions />
<global-forwards />
<action-mappings>
        <action path="/SwitchAction"  type="org.apache.struts.actions.SwitchAction"/>
 </action-mappings>
<message-resources parameter="com.yourcompany.struts.ApplicationResources" />
</struts-config>
```

struts-config-Admin.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

   <struts-config>
    <data-sources />
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="adminLoginForm" type="Admin.Form.AdminLoginForm" />
        <form-bean name="adminUserCreationForm" type="Admin.Form.AdminUserCreationForm" />


    </form-beans>

    <global-exceptions />
    <global-forwards />
    <action-mappings>
        <action attribute="AdminLoginForm" input="/AdminModule/AdminLogin.jsp"
            name="adminLoginForm" path="/AdminLogin" scope="request"
            type="Admin.Action.AdminLoginAction">
            <set-property property="cancellable" value="true" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/AdminErrorPage.jsp" />
            <forward name="success" path="/AdminHomePage.jsp" />
        </action>
        <action attribute="adminUserCreationForm" input="/AdminModule/AdminUserCreation.jsp"
            name="adminUserCreationForm" path="/AdminUserCreation" scope="request"
            type="Admin.Action.AdminUserCreationAction">
            <set-property property="cancellable" value="true" />
            <forward name="failure" path="/AdminModule/AdminErrorPage.jsp" />
            <forward name="success" path="/AdminModule/AdminSuccessPage.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

AdminUserCreationAction.java

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <base href="<%=basePath%>"    
    </head>

    <body>
        User Creation Page
        <html:form action="/AdminUserCreation">
            AdminName : <html:text property="username"/><html:errors property="username"/><br/>
            Password : <html:password property="password"/><html:errors property="password"/><br/>
            <html:submit/>
        </html:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

AdminUserCreationForm.java

```
package Admin.Form;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class AdminUserCreationForm extends ActionForm {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

AdminUserCreation.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%> 
    </head>
    <body>
        User Creation Page
        <html:form action="/AdminUserCreation">
            AdminName : <html:text property="username"/><html:errors property="username"/><br/>
            Password : <html:password property="password"/><html:errors property="password"/><br/>
            <html:submit/>
        </html:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

error im getting in browser

```
 type Exception report

     message 

     description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

     exception 

     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AdminUserCreation
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

     javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AdminUserCreation
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.AdminModule.AdminUserCreation_jsp._jspService(AdminUserCreation_jsp.java:114)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

     javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AdminUserCreation
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:759)
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:443)
    org.apache.jsp.AdminModule.AdminUserCreation_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(AdminUserCreation_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jsp.AdminModule.AdminUserCreation_jsp._jspService(AdminUserCreation_jsp.java:104)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


     note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.13 logs.
```

msg im gettng in console

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AdminUserCreation
 at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:759)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:443)
    at org.apache.jsp.AdminModule.AdminUserCreation_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(AdminUserCreation_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jsp.AdminModule.AdminUserCreation_jsp._jspService(AdminUserCreation_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: i have tried doing <html:form action="/AdminUserCreation.do"> also in jsp page..but same error is coming

Comment: "Cannot retrieve mapping for action /AdminUserCreation" ... Are you sure that struts-config-Admin.xml is loaded (read by struts)? Also that's too much code. You should post relevant code and with stacktrace if you others to go through your question.

Comment: struts-config is loading ...from home page(ie adminlogin or userlogin) to adminlogin is working fine and in adminlogin page also im able to login....after login im unable to process to create user

Comment: Can you check in struts-config.xml (in your war) if there is a action-mapping with `path="/AdminUserCreation"`?

Comment: its thr...with same name

Answer (score 0):

there is something a bit odd here (though it may not be the only cause of the problem) :

in your struts config file, you have defined

```
<action attribute="adminUserCreationForm" .....
            type="Admin.Action.AdminUserCreationAction">
```

which implies that class AdminUserCreationAction should be found under the Admin.Action package.

however, your AdminUserCreationAction class is declared under Admin.Form package :

```
package Admin.Form;
public class AdminUserCreationForm ...
```

please try to use the same package name in both cases.